# After locating an element with selenium, can you trace back/report back the xpath of the element?

Tags: python

I've been searching for a long time and still couldn't find an answer...

I can find the element by literally searching through every single divs in the website
but that's obviously very stupid, is there a way to trace back xpath so next time
I can use the xpath it got earlier when I rerun the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate the full Xpath of an element, you can simply use the Google Chrome console and inspect the element that you want, do

`Right Click -> Copy -> Copy Xpath/Copy Full Xpath`

or in code, walk up the tree from your element to root and compile a full Xpath.

If you are talking a partial Xpath locator such as `//input[@id='hello']`, there is no implemented feature for that yet. However, you can write your own function that takes in an element and analyzes it to get its attribute, such as its element type and id, and return a complied Xpath.